# ASP.NET and Entity Framework Case In-Sensitive Query From Oracle Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Using ASP.NET and Entity Framework 4 I am trying to get data from Oracle database by this code:

```
MapEntities togo = new MapEntities();
var items = togo.CONTRACTORTBL.Where(x=> x.CONTRACTORNAME.Contains(txtSearch.Text));
GridView1.DataSource = items.ToList();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

This is taking an string from `txtSearch.Text` text box and return to `GridView1` all match rows but it cares about case sensivity. I mean if I have a "mapa" in the `CONTRACTORNAME` field and the `txtSearch.Text = "Mapa"`, the query will not return any thing!

Can you please let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe try something like this:

```
var items = togo.CONTRACTORTBL.Where(x=> 
            x.CONTRACTORNAME.ToUpper().Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToUpper());
```

This will force both your search key as well as your source to both be in uppercase for the purposes of substring matching (without actually modifying what you have in the database.